# Bar plot in python for categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I am trying to create a bar for one of the column in dataset.
Column name is glucose and need a bar plot for three categoric values 0-100, 1-150, 151-200.

```
X=dataset('Glucose')

X.head(20)

0     148
1      85
2     183
3      89
4     137
5     116
6      78
7     115
8     197
9     125
10    110
11    168
12    139
13    189
14    166
15    100
16    118
17    107
18    103
19    115
```

not sure which approach to follow. could anyone please guide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.cut (Assuming X is a series) with value_counts:

```
pd.cut(X,[0,100,150,200]).value_counts().plot.bar()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks lot. But i wants bins 0-100, 101-150, 151-200. Could you please advice how to do that.

Comment: @ashish_goy that is what pd cut does in my code above. Could you please elaborate what you are looking for as the code above splits your column un the bins you said

Comment: in above plot bins are 0-100, 100-150 and 150-200 but my requirement is to create bins for following range: 0-100, 101-150 and 151-200.

Comment: @ashish_goy well you can play around with the bins to get that, may be try something like `pd.cut(X,[0,100,101,150,151,200])....` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: thanks @anky. found the answer. Thanks for the documents.

Answer (score 0):

bins=pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0,100),(101,150),(151,200)])

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.